# How to get SSN from intuit quick books employee obj

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

iam expecting some support on quick book development
I am planning to import the employee details of a quickbook employee to local DB , and when i fetch the object from QbuickBooks what iam getting is

```
SSN         ID         Name           Status 
XXX-XX-XXXX 29  caregiberneee       NotProcessed    
XXX-XX-XXXX 40  Aaron A Anderson    NotProcessed
```

Here i need to get the value of ssn, how can i decrypt it ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Here i need to get the value of ssn, how can i decrypt it ??

You can't.

It's not encrypted - it's masked and the real SSN is simply not returned to you at all.

Intuit does not make the actual SSN available via the API.